# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.handleOrientationChanged

Tags: android, qt

I built my Android app with [QT 5.15.2](https://developernote.com/2020/05/building-qt-5-15-0-for-android-on-windows/), published it in Google Play and started to get this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.handleOrientationChanged (Native Method)
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate$4.onDisplayChanged (QtActivityDelegate.java:676)
  at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage (DisplayManagerGlobal.java:1426)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

This also rarely happened before with QT 5.15.0.

What can cause this?

I do not know if this relate to the crash somehow but in the manifest I have

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

**EDIT1:** It happens mostly on Android 10.

Found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659130/no-implementation-found-for-void-org-qtproject-qt5-android-qtnative-handleorient).

Comment: I do see the same crashes on Google Play - have you found any solution to this crash yet?

Comment: @Michael The solution was to upload APK instead of ABB, see my post https://developernote.com/2020/02/packaging-qt-application-into-android-app-bundle/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense as I started using AAB only recently.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually checked your APK to contain the mentioned symbols?

I presume they should be located in the qtforandroid.so which should be actually named either libplugins_platforms_qtforandroid_arm64-v8a.so or libplugins_platforms_qtforandroid_armeabi-v7a.so when deployed with the application.

It is possible that symbols are stripped away by Gradle or other build system if you use it in your project.